# Windows phone is unable to set the VHD on the virtual machine

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, virtual-machine, hyper-v

I wanted to write some application on windows phone, but when i turned on emulator had been displayed this error:[image]

next step I opened the hyper-virtual management and tried to add new virtual machine using an existing virtual hard disk from windows phone emulator:

[image]

and when i clicked `next` that window is shown:

[image]

I had to use `close` button and clicked `finish`:

[image]

Last step I tried to create new machine:

[image]
[image]

And shows this windows:
[image]

Maybe you know how to repair my important problem?

Edit:
My services is that:

[image]

Last time i had to install xampp. When i did it my compouter slowed and i had to remove and install apache + php + **mysql** manually. Maybe it has some impact?

Comment: Well it says the file may be corrupted.. Start with reinstalling SDK.. But this is a rather general software problem, probably your OS got messed up.

Comment: @walther , I did  it 30 minutes ago. No progress. You think that i have to reinstall windows and maybe it will give me good results?

Comment: Are you running a preview version of Windows by any chance? Or a malware could be messing with signing and/or signature verification...